# Build Spark SQL query dynamically

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How we can pass a column name and operator name dynamically to the SQL query with Spark in Scala?

I tried (unsuccessfully) the following:

```
spark.sql("set key_tbl=mytable")
spark.sql("select count(1) from ${key_tbl}").collect()
```

Answer (score 8):

You can pass it as parameter as shown below

```
val param = "tableName" 
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
sqlContext.sql(s"""SELECT * FROM param=$param""")
```

can check this link for more details 
https://forums.databricks.com/questions/115/how-do-i-pass-parameters-to-my-sql-statements.html

Comment: Should `s"""SELECT * FROM param=$param"""` actually be `s"""SELECT * FROM $param"""`?

Answer (score 5):

Quite more simply, you should be able to do something like the following:

```
val key_tbl = "mytable"
spark.sql(s"select count(1) from ${key_tbl}").collect()
```

Notice the `s` before the query string: this uses Scala's string interpolation to build the query with another variable (`key_tbl`).

You can read more on String interpolation in Scala [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
i done  with this ,as following:

val tablename="yourtablename"
val columnname="name"
val value=""
val operator="=="
spark.sql("select * from"+ tablename+"where"+name+operator+value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried and answer is :
You make query as :

```scala
s"""(SELECT * FROM param='$param')foo"""
```