# How to pass my schema and table name as variable in my spark SQL query

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, string-interpolation

I am getting different results when passing schema_name.table_name directly in query and schema_name.table name as variable
For example

```
Variable1="schema_name.table_name"

Val query1=spark.sql(s""" select* from $variable1""")

Val query2=spark.sql(select * From schema_name.table_name)
```

I am getting different result for query1 and query2

I have tried string interpolation and f-string but none worked for me

Comment: Spark can return different results because the order of rows isn't deterministic until you do `order by something`...

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48971231/build-spark-sql-query-dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Please use
Valquery1=spark.sql(f""" select * from {variable1}""")

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48971231/build-spark-sql-query-dynamically

Comment: this question is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48971231/build-spark-sql-query-dynamically